# Error about C_outflow[] when using FluidPort

Tags: modelica

i'm noob for modelica and developing the Heat Exchanger model.

I did input

```
air_in.X_outflow[1]=1;
air_out.X_outflowp[1]=1;
coolant_in.X_outflow[1]=1;
coolant_out.X_outflow[1]=1;
```

but I encountered some errors like captures below.
[image: error about C_outflow]

First, I don't know what is the physical meaning of C_outflow. I could find that C_outflow = c_i/m
and m is the mass of the fluid, but couldn't find the meaning of c_i.
Second, I've just tried to input the value 0~1 as the description said, but encountered the error message above. I think the value has not been input to the C_outflow array but I'm not sure.

Please reply to anyone who can figure out these problems... Thank you to all of you.

model Staggered_HX

Answer (score 1):

A complete model would be helpful - but attempting to answer anyway:

The C-array is an array of trace substances, and there are normally no trace substances; whereas the X-array is the array of normal substances - which must contain some elements.

For the C-array it would thus be: `air_in.C_outflow=zeros(0);` (where `zeros(0)` creates an empty vector - corresponding to no trace substabces), but I don't see how that relates to the equations above with `air_in.X_outflow[1]=1;`

Comment: Thank you to reply. Code in the post was my fault, not X but C i did input. Plus, could you tell me what the exact meaning of trace component and physical meaning of c_i? Is that just a kind of trace component before being divided by mass?